# push elements into array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-update

I have a collection named test looks like the following json:

```
{
   '_id':ObjetcId("..."),
   'a':[
        {
          id:1,
          a1:[{x:1,y:1},{x:10,y:11},{x:10,y:12}],
          flag:1
        },
        { 
          id:2
          a1:[{x:1,y:1},{x:10,y:11},{x:10,y:12}],
          flag:0
        },
       ]
}
```

Now I want to push an another `({x：99，y:99})` element into `a.a1` with condition that `a.id=1`, I tried the command:

```
db.test.update({'_id':ObjectId('...')},{"$push":{"a.a1":{x:99,y:99}}})
```

and return error message that can't use the part(a of a.a1 ) to traverse the elements,so how should I add the element to the array?

Comment: you mean push to all a.a1 ?

Comment: @kiro112 no to all ,with condition a.id=1

Comment: @kiro112 it works! Thank you ^_^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mongodb positional/$](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/)
The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array. To project, or return, an array element from a read operation, see the $ projection operator.

```
db.test.update({ 
    _id: ObjectId('...'),
    "a.id": 1 
}, { 
    $push: { 
        "a.$.a1": { x: 99, y: 99 } 
    } 
})
```